# Heat transfer: boundary conditions with fluid velocity

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, heat-equation

The following equation is considered:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - a\Delta u + \mathbf v \cdot \nabla u = f.
$$
I have difficulties in formulating boundary conditions for this equation.
If $\mathbf v$ is absent, the boundary conditions are
$$
a\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} + \beta(u - u_b) = 0
$$
where $u_b$ is prescribed temperature field on the boundary.
But if $\mathbf v$ is present? If we suggest the following boundary condition:
$$
a\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} - (\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n) + \beta(u - u_b) = 0
$$
then we will have problems with analysing the equation when $(\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n) > 0$ (where the fluid outflows).
How to set correct boundary conditions?

Comment: Is the fluid velocity a known function, i.e., $\mathbf{v}$ is prescribed? If that's not the case, the Navier-Stokes equations for pressure and velocity are missing.

Comment: @Dmoreno Yes, $\mathbf v$ is prescribed.

Answer (score 1):

The boundary condition 
$$
a\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} - (\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n)u + \beta(u - u_b) = 0
$$
is correct and  cannot cause a problem. Indeed, $\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf n=0$ at the boundary whenever it happens to be impermeable to fluid. Otherwise,  condition $(\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf n) > 0$ cannot hold on the whole boundary according to the principle of conservation of mass implying that the total flux of fluid through the boundary equals zero.

Comment: This is a typo. Here is a condition:

$a\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} - (\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n)u + \beta(u - u_b) = 0$ or $a\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} - (\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n)(u - u_b) + \beta(u - u_b) = 0 $.

$(\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n) > 0$ on the part of the boundary.

Comment: @jokersobak: In the boundary condition for the temperature, yes. An obvious typo, though I missed it. But condition $a\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} - (\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n)(u - u_b) + \beta(u - u_b) = 0$ won't do since $-a\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} + (\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n)u$ is a heat flux density through any surface, including the boundary at which it must be proportional to the difference between inside and outside temperature. This is exactly what is called a convective heat transfer at the boundary.

Comment: Here the condition $a\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} - (\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n)(u - u_b) + \beta(u - u_b) = 0$ is suggested:
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/169199/heat-transfer-boundary-conditions-with-fluid-velocity/169207?noredirect=1#comment428553_169207

Comment: In this case we should impose the condition $\beta \geq (\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n)$. Why is it so (physically)?

Comment: @jokersobak: Carlo Beenakker's argument is wrong because he incorrectly takes $\,-a\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}\,$ for the total heat flux density while it should be $\,-a\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} + (\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n)u$. In fact, $\,-a\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}\,$ is just a partial heat flux density provided by the Fourier law.

Comment: He asserts that it is $-a\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} + (\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n)(u - u_b)$.

Comment: @jokersobak: No, the total heat flux density has nothing to do with an outside temperature. The total heat flux density  is a basic element in the derivation of the heat equation for continuous media. It is defined on any smooth geometrical surface inside continuous media, and circumstantially on inside part of the boundary where it could be equated to the partial heat influx density $(\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n)u_b$. But this would be another boundary regime quite different from the purely convective heat transfer.

Comment: @mkl314 --- perhaps this discussion (on whether the $v\cdot n$ in the boundary condition should be multiplied by $u$ or by $u-u_b$) can be settled by just considering what would happen if you would open a window in your room; there's a draft ($v\cdot n\neq 0$), but the temperature inside and outside is the same ($u=u_b$). Surely one would not expect a temperature gradient to appear?

Comment: @ Carlo Beenakker: There's no draft with just one window open $(v\cdot n\approx 0)$. With two windows open, there's a significant draft, while a noticeable temperature gradient 
is being transported inside through one window, proceeding then outside through another. Near the first window (incoming flow), a temperature looks like $T=\theta(x-vt)$ and surely feels like $\theta'\not\equiv 0$. Though it seems that thermal diffusivity $a$ might be neglected $(a\approx 0)$ without any loss of generality for this experiment.